# Email Template Character (∞) Displayed differently for Outlook and Gmail (and others)

Tags: html, email, html-email, email-client

Are there any solutions to always display the specific character (∞) the same way for different email clients?

This part of the email template:

```
<tr>
  <td>Price €</td>
  <td>{{search_requests__min_price}} - ∞</td>
</tr>
```

Hot it looks for me (Gmail - Good):
[image]

How it looks for others (Outlook - Bad):
[image]

Comment: The simple answer is: use the same font. I suspect you haven't set any, so mail clients use their own defaults – which may vary across different clients.

Comment: @MCEmperor Got it, thank you! Do you know how to locate the character in the middle of the text? (see the difference between screenshots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MC Emporer said in the comments below the original question, the best way to define a system font that exists on most platforms. Arial is a good candidate.

```
<table style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;">
  <tr>
    <td>Price €</td>
    <td>{{search_requests__min_price}} - ∞</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Defining the font in a parent container will cascade down all the text below.

Note: You still will be at the mercy of the OS. Eg. Windows and Mac will display the fonts differently. And Windows Outlook uses MS Word to render text.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason, it is not working properly only on the Google Phone (as one team member reported). Do you know what can cause this issue?

Comment: @Neilord Specifically what isn't working? What do you want to happen and what's happening instead?

Comment: The font for the message on Google Phone is not what I have selected in the `style` (the post issue). It is not working only on Google Phone. Do you what can cause this issue? Can Google Phone use its own fonts (even if the font is specified)?

Comment: Depending on the phone and email client, it might not support the `<style>` tag (use inline CSS instead) or support web fonts (use system fonts instead).

Comment: it is working, man! Thanks a lot for your help on this one!

Comment: @Neilord Nice! Glad I could help.